# Can't get second controller to work on Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had two pages - a `signup page` and a `login page`. I now want to integrate both forms onto my `home page`. I added a reference to both controllers in my `HomepageModule.js` but the sign up functionality isn't working. Here are my files, what am I doing wrong?

Homepage.ejs:

```
<body ng-app="HomepageModule" ng-cloak>
    <form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()" ng-controller="HomepageController">
        <!-- Some Inputs -->
    </form>
   <div ng-controller="SignupController"
    <form ng-submit="submitSignupForm()" id="sign-up-form" class="form-signin" name="signup">
        <!-- Some Inputs -->
    </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

HomepageModule:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('HomepageModule', ['toastr', 'compareTo','ngMaterial'])
    .controller('HomepageController', function($scope) {
      $scope.isOpen = false;
      $scope.demo = {
        isOpen: false,
        count: 0,
        selectedDirection: 'left'
      };
    })
    .controller('SignupController', function($scope) {
      $scope.isOpen = false;
      $scope.demo = {
        isOpen: false,
        count: 0,
        selectedDirection: 'left'
      };
    });
})();
```

HomepageController.js:

```
angular.module('HomepageModule').controller('HomepageController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr){

    $scope.loginForm = {
        loading: false
    }

    $scope.submitLoginForm = function (){
    }
    //other app logic
}]);
```

SignupController.js:

```
angular.module('HomepageModule').controller('SignupController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr){

    // set-up loading state
    $scope.signupForm = {
        loading: false
    }

    $scope.submitSignupForm = function(){
    }
        //other app logic
    }]);
```

Edit:

The areas I am most suspicious of are the `angular.module('HomepageModule').controller('SignupController', ...` lines, should they reference `HomepageModule` from both controllers? Also, is the syntax for including both controllers in the module correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ng-controller in sign up form `<form ng-submit="submitSignupForm()" ng-controller="SignupController" ...`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in the question, please see now.

Comment: maybe its problem with `Angular` instead of `angular` in SignupController.js

Answer (score 0):

This will allow both controllers to exist. Right now, only HompageController exists on the page.

```
 <body ng-app="HomepageModule" ng-cloak>
    <form ng-submit="HC.submitLoginForm()" ng-controller="HomepageController as HC">
        <!-- Some Inputs -->
    </form>
    <form ng-submit="SC.submitSignupForm()" ng-controller="SingupController as SC" id="sign-up-form" class="form-signin" name="signup">
        <!-- Some Inputs -->
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the as HC/SC mean/do?

Comment: Just lets you access both on the page at once if they're overlapping. Not necessary in this use case.

Comment: hmmm, I am afraid that still isn't working... that way neither controller seems to be working. If I remove all the SC/HC references then I am back to only Login working

Comment: Try adding a div or span around each form, with ng-controller="HompageController" and the other one around the other form.

Comment: That throws this error `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SingupController' is not a function, got undefined` and my SignUp form isn't displaying...

Comment: my bad, it is displaying just not working... The bits I am suspicious of, is the way I added the controller too the HomepageModule and the angular.module lines, should those both be homepagemodule?